# Copied WIT won't calculate remaining time in Backlog bord

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem, workitem, queueuserworkitem

i've copied the WIT "User Story", made it a new WIT and renamed it to "PR". The work item also has "Remaining Work" and "Original Estimate". But when i enter times it wont get calculated in the board.

On the other hand, "Bug" get's calculated just right. I've already checked the fields and they are the same (Field Control, VSTS.Sheduling.RemaningWork, Type Double, reaportable Measure, formula SUM and so on)

any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are required to get TFS to handle those fields the way you describe. First check your `ProcessConfiguration.xml` file (in the folder: `.\WorkItem Tracking\Process` of your process template). Check which field is configured as Remaining Work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectProcessConfiguration>
  <TypeFields>
    <TypeField refname="System.AreaPath" type="Team" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" type="RemainingWork" format="{0} h" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank" type="Order" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints" type="Effort" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity" type="Activity" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationStartInformation" type="ApplicationStartInformation" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationLaunchInstructions" type="ApplicationLaunchInstructions" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationType" type="ApplicationType">
```

...

In the above example you can see that `Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork` is used as the `RemainingWork` field. Make sure that your PR WIT uses this field and not a custom field that has the same label, the refname must be `Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork`

```
<FIELD name="Remaining Work" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" type="Double" reportable="measure" formula="sum">
        <HELPTEXT>An estimate of the number of units of work remaining to complete this task</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
```

Next in the same file check what category is configured as the "task level":

```
<TaskBacklog category="Microsoft.TaskCategory" pluralName="Tasks" singularName="Task" workItemCountLimit="1000">
    <States>
      <State value="New" type="Proposed" />
...
</TaskBacklog>
```

In the above example you can see that `Microsoft.TaskCategory` is configured as the category to use as the task backlog.

Next check your categories.xml file (in the `.\WorkItem` Tracking folder of your process template) and verify that the WIT you created is in the task category:

```
<CATEGORY name="Task Category" refname="Microsoft.TaskCategory">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Task" />
  </CATEGORY>
```

Note that if you expect the remaing work of tasks to roll-up to your PR WIT then the PR WIT should be in the `Microsoft.RequirementCategory`.

If you want to update your existing team project(s) you will have to use [witadmin.exe](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/witadmin/witadmin-customize-and-manage-objects-for-tracking-work). Use `exportprocessconfig` and `importprocessconfig` for the process configuration. Use `exportcategories` and `importcategories` for the categories.